# Soundcloud Download Timeout

Tags: ios, http, download, titanium, soundcloud

Is anyone from soundcloud looking at this? Why am I getting a 403 for a valid request?

I am building an iOS app at the moment using Titanium.

I am including a new feature that allows users to download Soundcloud .mp3 files and play them from the app (Saving to the application directory)

The code I have written is working fine for some of the tracks, but not for others.  The client has unlimited downloads for all tracks, and I have increased the max timeout quite a lot, and it still just downloads around 170 bytes then fails on some of the tracks. On others it downloads the whole track with no issues. Really stumped with this one, anyone got any ideas?

Below is the code and also an example of a track working, and one not working if anyone can see a difference?

Thanks

Justin

```
//Download code


var newDir = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'scDownloads');

    newDir.createDirectory();

    var id = fStripped;

    var dlXhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
        timeout : 500000});

    dlXhr.onload = function(){
        var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(newDir.resolve(),id +'.mp3');

        Ti.API.warn('file is: ' + file);

        file.createFile();

        file.write(this.responseData);

    }

    dlXhr.open('GET',dlURL + '?client_id=' + soundcloudClientID);

    dlXhr.send();
```

And here are a couple of tracks (With client ID)

This one works: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/60943956/download?client_id=7a0984726d0eefbb310771c4c02116a8

This one doesn't: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/63980557/download?client_id=7a0984726d0eefbb310771c4c02116a8

I have tested this on Soundcloud's API console (http://developers.soundcloud.com/console) and got the following:

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:
Date
X-Runtime:
20
Age:
0
Content-Length:
28
X-Cacheable:
NO:Cache-Control=no-cache
Location:
gda=1351783496_b465064be1b41027a7a0bf6067d83169">http://ak-media.soundcloud.com/kw7JNYi7HtCq?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4IAZE5EOI7PA7VQ&Expires=1351783496&Signature=UNtBsSfBh1XNvXPLSLNVzTQEclY%3D&**gda**=1351783496_b465064be1b41027a7a0bf6067d83169
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
Connection:
close
Server:
nginx
X-Cache:
MISS
Cache-Control:
no-cache
X-Varnish:
1398398080
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin
Date:
Thu, 01 Nov 2012 15:24:36 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
*
Via:
1.1 varnish
Content-Type:
application/xml; charset=utf-8

302 - Found

I also added a Ti.API.debug(e.error); to the dlXhr.onerror function I have created, and this simply returned

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting a 403 for the one that "doesn't". You should listen for the onerror event, and handle it appropriately. Also, you should stream the file rather than keeping it in memory than writing out out all at once. Take advantage of the "file" property available on Ti.Network.HTTPClient on iOS to do this simply. Plus, show progress, because that's a huge file you're downloading. The below sample demonstrates all of this:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: 'white'
});
var progressBar = Ti.UI.createProgressBar({
    max: 1, min: 0, value: 0,
    left: 20, right: 20,
    height: 20,
    visible: true
});
win.add(progressBar);
win.open();

var fileName = 'file.mp3';
var link = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/63980557/download?client_id=7a0984726d0eefbb310771c4c02116a8';
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, fileName);

var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    ondatastream: function (e) {
        progressBar.value = e.progress;
    },
    onload: function () {
        alert('Download Complete: ' + file.size);
    },
    onerror: function (e) {
        alert(client.status);
    }
});
client.open('GET', link);
client.file = file;
client.send();
```

Comment: Hi Dawson, I shall add the onerror function, just havent got that far yet, Streaming is already in the app and works fine (There is a version live now with no issues), the point here is that the download problem is consistent, not random. Certain tracks work, others don't which is making me wonder if it's something to do with Soundcloud.

Comment: So I have just captured an error....it's quite useless. {source = "[object TiNetworkClient]"; type = error; That is literally all it says

Comment: If you look at the client.status, you'll see you're getting a 403.

Comment: Hi Dawson, please see my edits above, I have tested this on Soundcloud's own API console, and it gives me a 302, which is the same for all tracks, regardless of whether I could download them through the app or not. I believe the console returns this if the request is valid. I added a debug line, which is returning <null> so  in my eyes this suggests to me that there is no error coming from Soundcloud. I am unsure as to why it would be giving a 403

Comment: 403 Forbidden You don't have access to whatever it is you're asking for. Yet I get a 302 which is correct when I put the same GET request through the API console?

Comment: Is anyone from soundcloud looking at this? Why am I getting a 403 for a valid request?